# Ionic 3 loading Google Pay library

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, google-pay

I'm trying to implement Google Pay to my Ionic app. As I didn't find any convenient library matching both, I tried to use what is described here

https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/tutorial#full-example.

Problem: loading the pay.js library

[image]

I don't know how to load the library pay.js in my Ionic project.

I hope that's pretty clear.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first include the pay.js library.

The preferred method is to include the script in your page:

```html
<script src="https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js" async></script>
```

Alternatively, if you need to load it with JavaScript you could [dynamically load the script](https://javascript.info/promise-basics#loadscript):

```js
function loadScript(src) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;

    script.onload = () => resolve(script);
    script.onerror = () => reject(new Error(`Script load error for ${src}`));

    document.head.append(script);
  });
}

loadScript('https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js')
  .then(() => getGooglePayPaymentsClient());
```

For code completion in supported editors, you can use the [@types/googlepay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/googlepay) package:

```sh
npm install --save-dev @types/googlepay
```